# Kendo grid read action trigering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid and i am creating the grid in `document.ready` function.Initially while creating the grid it does not have a read.But after selecting a value i have to populate the grid with certian values from the database.So i want to trigger the read of kendo grid after selecting the value.So at that time i want to give the path for read action.Is it possible??

For exampe

in the document.ready i am creating the datasource for grid like this

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging    : true,
    serverSorting   : true,
    serverFiltering : true,
    serverGrouping  : true,
    serverAggregates: true,
    transport: {
        read: {    
        },
        update: {   
        }
    }
});
```

And when the user selects a value from a field i have to set the url fro read
Say name is the field where user selects a value
So

```
$("#name").change(function(){
   //set read action here and read data for the grid
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var _theUrl;

dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverGrouping: true,
    serverAggregates: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: function() { return _theUrl; }
        },
        update: {

        }
    }
})

$("#name").change(function(){
   _theUrl = "URLHere.aspx";
   dataSource.read();
});
```